# A way to access a Non-public member from DragEventArgs

Tags: c#, silverlight, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop list box, when the user moves an item into the box the Drop method is fired.

in this method i want to get the name of the object that was dropped in the listbox, below is what i want to add to a string variable;

[image: DragEventArgs Data()]

I have tried the `list.GetData` and the `list.GetDataPresent()` but these just return null. how would i access this to return a string of 'Combo List'?

Comment: There's generally a reason why these items are non-public. You could possibly use reflection. Is this a good idea though? Possibly not if only for the performance implications.

Comment: Can you get that data via list.GetData(...) ?